# Pointwise and uniform convergence for $f_n(x) = \sin^2(\pi x)(\chi_{[n, n+1]})$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

> Let $f_n(x) = \sin^2(\pi x)(\chi_{[n, n+1]})$.

I need to find its pointwise limit, and show if it converges uniformly. Also I am asked if $f_n(x_n) \to  f(x_0) $ $\; \forall x_n\to x_0 $ in R.

I am encountering $\chi$ notation for the first time so I am not sure what is going here. I know that $f_n(x)$ are zero outside $[n,n+1]$

for the pointwise limit:

I am assuming as $n\to \infty $, then $[n, n+1]$ becomes $\phi$ so intuitively $f_n(x) \to 0$ pointwise. But I don't think this is a rigorous proof.

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a fixed $x$, choose an $n_{0}$ such that $n_{0}>x$, then for all $n\geq n_{0}$, $x\notin[n,n+1]$, and hence $f_{n}(x)=0$, so $f_{n}\rightarrow 0$ pointwise.

It is not uniform since $\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}f_{n}(x)=1$.

Comment: Also : let $x_n \to x_0\in R$  then $\exists n_0 > x_0 +2 \in N$ such that $x_n \in (x_0-0.5, x_0 + 0.5) \; \forall n\geq n_0$ and $f_n(x_n ) = 0 = f(x_0) \forall n\geq n_0$ so $f_n(x_n) \to f(x_0) \; forall x_n \to x_0$  would this be correct?

Comment: Okay it sounds valid.

Comment: thanks for help